# Comparing two different folders with Regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I want to compare if one file is in two different folders.

```
var reg = new Regex(@"TC__\d{3,4}_8exp$");
var reg1 = new Regex(@"TC_\d{3,4}$");
  
var FileNames_List_Jetzt_Dateien = Directory.GetFiles(@"PATH2", "*.html")
           .Where(path => reg.IsMatch(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path)))
           .Select(Folder_Jetzt_Dateien =>
               Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Folder_Jetzt_Dateien));
```

From this one I am getting list :

```
TC__6493_8exp
TC__6494_8exp
TC__6495_8exp...
```

From this one:

```
var TEST_FÄLLE = Directory.GetFiles(@"PATH2", "*.exp")
          .Where(path => reg1.IsMatch(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path)))
          .Select(Folder_Jetzt_Dateien =>
              Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Folder_Jetzt_Dateien));
```

I am getting list:

```
TC_6493
TC_6494
TC_6495...
```

For me the **TC__6493_8exp** is the same with **TC_6493**. How to use **Intersect** for these two lists with the same elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to write the custom comparer with a regex:

```cs
public static Regex rx = new Regex(@"^(TC_)_?(\d+).*", RegexOptions.Compiled);
public class FilePathComparer : IEqualityComparer<string>
{
    public bool Equals(string x, string y)
    {
        return rx.Replace(x, "$1$2") == rx.Replace(y, "$1$2");
    }
    public int GetHashCode(string s)
    {
        return rx.Replace(s,"$1$2").GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

In the code later, just use

```cs
var intersected = FileNames_List_Jetzt_Dateien.Intersect(TEST_FÄLLE, new FilePathComparer());
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/t7liBp) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9Xgcey/1).

The `^(TC_)_?(\d+).*` regex matches

- `^` - start of string
- `(TC_)` - Group 1 (`$1`): `TC_`
- `_?` - an optional underscore
- `(\d+)` - Group 2 (`$2`): one or more digits
- `.*` - the rest of the string.

Answer (score 2):

You can write custom comparer and pass it to `Intersect` method

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;

class FileComparer : IEqualityComparer<string>
{
    const string ext = "_exp8";
    
    public bool Equals(string left, string right)
    {
        if (left.EndsWith(ext) && !right.EndsWith(ext))
        {
            return StripExt(left) == right;
        }
        else if (right.EndsWith(ext))
        {
            return left == StripExt(right);
        }
            
        return left == right;
    }
    
    private static string StripExt(string s)
        => s.Substring(0, s.Length - ext.Length);
    
    public int GetHashCode(string s)
    {
        if (s.EndsWith(ext))
        {
            return StripExt(s).GetHashCode();
        }
        else
        {
            return s.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;

var files1 = new string[] { "1", "2", "3" };
var files2 = new string[] { "1_ext", "2_exp8", "3_exp8" };

var a = files1.Intersect(files2, new FileComparer());

var res = string.Join(", ", a);
Console.WriteLine(res);
```